# My Fusion Drive unlinked in two pieces (SSD+HDD) and I want to restore it again in one piece

Tags: imac, disk-utility, core-storage, fusion-drive

i have an iMac 27′ late 2012 and I have a problem with my Fusion Drive … suddenly the SSD part and the HDD unlinked and now i have two separate disks .. I ran in Terminal: `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list` witht he following results:

[image]

Can somebody help me how to continue from here to link the two disks again in one (Fusion Drive as previous).

---

Update: After deleting the Logical Volume Groups I get the following partition table:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To recreate a Fusion Drive you have to delete both Logical Volume Groups and create a new one. This will delete all data on both volumes "Macintosh HD".

- Booted to Recovery Mode open in the menubar Utilities > Terminal
- In Terminal enter `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list`.
- Check that both disks (disk0 and disk1) are the internal disks with a size of 120 GB and 1 TB/3TB depending on your Fusion drive.
- Delete both Logical Volume Groups with:

  ```
  diskutil cs delete lvgUUID #with lvgUUID: the UUID of the Logical Volume Group
  ```

  In your case that's:

  ```
  diskutil cs delete DD7FD...
  diskutil cs delete 597C4...
  ```

  Please use the complete UUIDs - I'm too lazy to write them down completely.
- Rebuild the Fusion Drive with:

  ```
  diskutil cs create FusionDrive disk0s2 disk1s2
  ```

  This will create a new Logical Volume Group
- Enter `diskutil cs list` to get the new lvgUUID
- To create a new Logical Volume enter:

  ```
  diskutil cs createVolume new_lvgUUID jhfs+ "Macintosh HD" 0g
  ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46263/discussion-on-answer-by-klanomath-my-fusion-drive-unlinked-in-two-pieces-ssdhd).